# C# -> Retrieving dataset from SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

I have a table called `NAMES` in my SQL Server database. I am trying to retrieve the entire table and put it into a dataset:

```
//get the connection string from web.config
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Platform"].ConnectionString;
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();                
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("NAMES", conn);
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
}
```

This throws a sql exception though,

> "Invalid Object Name NAMES"...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from [NAMES]", conn);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the connection !!!!!!

```
 //get the connection string from web.config
 string connString = ConfigurationManager .ConnectionStrings["Platform"].ConnectionString;
 DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
 {
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();                
     adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from [NAMES]", conn);
     conn.Open(); 
     adapter.Fill(dataset);
 }
```

Comment: opening the connection would certainly help but I don't think that is the exception you'd see. Invalid object name certainly suggests that it had reached the database. I assume the code above is a cut down version that just accidentally omitted the DB opening.

Comment: Can you access the database through SQL management studio to check if this table really exists

Comment: Actually, using the `SqlDataAdapter` you **don't** have to open the connection yourself - the adapter **will** do this for you!

Comment: when using sqldataadapter you don't open the connection, the adapter opens and close the connection by itself

Answer (score 7):

You're not passing an actual SQL select command to the `SqlCommand` constructor.

Comment: if I change "NAMES" to "SELECT * FROM NAMES" I still get the same error

Comment: Have you tried `[NAMES]` instead (as per @AmenAyach's suggestion)? Names is an ODBC reserved keyword and is thus goign to cause potential confusion in parsing SQL unless you escape it properly.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether Select * from dbo.[Names]  is wroking in ur sql ?

```
     string connString = ConfigurationManager .ConnectionStrings["Platform"].ConnectionString;
        Dataset ds=new Dataset();
        SqlConnection con = new Sqlconnection(connString);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from dbo.[Names]",con);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
```